# "Additional" standard deviation?

Tags: distributions, standard-deviation

I have a train station where trains arrive at certain intervals called headways. I know the distribution of headways for a "regular" situation and a "disrupted" situation.

Standard deviations of headways indicate reliability and I want to compute how "less" reliable the disrupted situation is compared to the regular one.

If std(disrupted)=200 seconds and std(regular)=20 seconds, can I say that the additional std of the disrupted situation compared to the regular one is 180 seconds? Or do I need to go back to the variance?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you call it ' difference in standard deviation'?

Comment: Are you trying to say that std(disrupted) - std(regular) = 180? If so, then, by your set up, yes. However, generally speaking we're likely to perform linear combinations (such as addition or subtraction of random variables) with Variances (because it has nice mathematical properties) and then square root the answer to get the standard deviation, which is why you may have seen it expressed as a variance online or in your textbook.

Comment: Anne, if you claim that disrupted headway = regular situation + disruption where the disruption term adds to the regular time and is independent of it then you should be adding variances.  adding st dev is appropriate if you claim 100% correlation between regular timing and additional effect of disruption.

Comment: @fcop Yes it is a difference in standard deviation.

Comment: @seanv507 but if I take the square root of the sum of the squares (sqrt (200*200+20*20)) then when std are identical, I do not get a difference of 0. So what if I take the sqrt of the difference, (sqrt (200*200-20*20))? (making sure that the number in the sqrt is positive)

Comment: Anne, yes you are correct you would take the sqrt of difference - *because you are claiming*  regular time and disruptive extra time are independent and have additive effect so those variances add ie total time variance = regular time variance + disruptive extra time variance ( and then you solve for disruptive extra time variance

Comment: @seanv507 thank you for replying again, as I wrote below, I agree to both your answer and that of Carl, but they are different.. Is there a difference I do not get?

Comment: Standard deviation is a measure of scale; this suggests that ratios of standard deviations may be more useful than differences.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can accurately say that there is an additional time, with one nit-picking caveat. That is, provided that you specify absolute time, and not negative time. That sounds rather picky, but consider the physical correctness, which has to be accounted for, just like statistical correctness. Standard deviations, provided they are taken of physical quantities that have sensible units, are also physical distances, and they are never negative. Physical distances if they are measured off-axis, i.e., obliquely to an axis, and provided the measurements are orthogonal, add by vector addition. When measured parallel to an axis, a vector addition of orthogonal variables reduces to absolute value of distance. In statistical language this sounds different, but is no different.

In your case, time is orthogonal to frequency of train arrival, and a positive distance in time is perfectly consistent with the units and direction of elapsing time. Absolute values of time can be added or subtracted provided they are parallel to the time axis, and not vectors oblique to the time axis.

In what case would the variances be in some sense "additive"? Suppose, for example, we wanted to calculate the standard deviation of a mixed schedule consisting of a fraction of both distributions so that they compose a mixture distribution, or a distribution with two bumps in it, one for the percentage of trains that are not disrupted, and one for the $1-$that percentage of trains that arrive during a disruptive event. This is done as per the [moments section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Moments) of the Wikipedia entry for mixture distributions:

In case of a mixture of one-dimensional distributions with weights $w_i$, means $μ_i$ and variances ${σ_i}^2$, the total mean and variance will be:

$\operatorname{E}[X] = \mu = \sum_{i = 1}^n w_i \mu_i$,

$\operatorname{E}[(X - \mu)^2] = \sigma^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n w_i((\mu_i - \mu)^{2} + \sigma_i^2)$

Please note, this is not the straight addition of variances, they have to be weighted to make any sense.

Comment: thank you for your answer. With "When measured parallel to an axis, a vector addition of orthogonal variables reduces to absolute value of distance", do you mean that the value of 180 seconds (200-20) is indeed correct? I would like to make sure I understand but I must admit that I struggle a bit.

Comment: Yes, correct. Try not to over think it. Standard deviations are absolute distances, in this case, in time. If one train is likely to arrive at a time 180 seconds more deviant than another, then it is what it is. The next question might be, what does one do with that number of seconds? The answer to which is "not much." For example, if one wanted to ask if the 180 second difference is significant, one might test [equality of variances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Tests_of_equality_of_variances).

Comment: Weird thing is, I understand and agree with both your answer and that of @seanv507, but they are different..

Answer (score 0):

you have to come up with a model and then 1 or both answers are wrong!

you are essentially assuming a model of form

$\text{disruptive time} = \text{regular time} + \text{disruptive effect}$

taking variances

$var(\text{disruptive time}) = var(\text{regular time} + \text{disruptive effect})$

$var(\text{disruptive time}) = var(\text{regular time}) + var(\text{disruptive effect}) + 2\rho std(\text{regular time})  std(\text{disruptive effect})$

where $\rho$ is the correlation between regular time and disruptive effect.

Now without knowing too much about your problem it sounds reasonable to assume there is no correlation ($\rho=0$) between the  regular variation and disruptive effect [eg different drivers add regular variation and weather adds disruptive effects].  if on the other hand you think that regular and disruptive effects are essentially 100% correlated ( which I doubt), eg slow drivers drive slower in bad weather and fast drivers drive even faster, then $\rho=1$ and you see that 
the standard deviations add:
$var(\text{disruptive time}) = (std(\text{regular time}) + std(\text{disruptive effect}))^2$

so $std(\text{disruptive time}) = std(\text{regular time}) + std(\text{disruptive effect})$

So you have to specify which model is correct for your situation (uncorrelated or 100% correlated)

Comment: @seavn507 I assumed independence, the data are not paired. I assumed something like 3000 trains in one group with 200 in another, some trains are seen once a day, some once a month, and some only once ever. I assume engineers show up for work at random times are random, conductors are sometimes on the trains and sometimes not, locomotives are random, railroad cars are random, number of passengers on and off loading is random, and may never reoccur in that station ever in that same combination. So, correlations of what to what exactly? BTW, do not jump to conclusions, Rather bad form, eh wot?

Comment: @seavn507 I cannot conceive of a physical circumstance in which the numbers and trains are either paired or equal or for which one would add unweighted variances correlated or not, nor a circumstances in which they are disruptive event trains correlate to non-disrupted event trains. A train is not any particular length, and is not a "unit" other that a scheduled event. The same train never arrives at the station twice, is a better assumption.

Comment: It's really nice of you two for providing your insights, thanks!